# populating hidden field from codebehind, then, passing it back to codebehind as QueryString ASP/javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have this code in page_load method:

```
string orgId = Session["Lineage"].ToString().Split(';')[depth];
hidOrg.Value = orgId;
```

This in the aspx page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidOrg" runat="server" />
```

and

```
function doRetrieveData(objVal) {

    var org = document.getElementById("hidOrg").value;
    //do stuff
    window.location.href = "summary.aspx?multiple=" + org
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting an object expected error when assigning var org the value of the hidden "hidOrg" field.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET generates server-control's ClientIDs according to the control's [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx). 
So you need to pass the `ClientID` to your javascript function. Try this:

```
var org = document.getElementById('<%=hidOrg.ClientID%>').value;
```

[Inline ASP.NET tags](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)

Other approaches:

1. Pass the hiddenfield's value to the javascript function as well. You need to put the hiddenfield directly behind the DropDownList/Select and use [nextSibling](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_node_nextsibling.asp) to get a reference to it.

   ```
   onchange="doRetrieveData(this.value,this.nextSibling.value)
   ```
2. Set the Hidden-Field's [ClientIdMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) to `Static` (if using .NET 4.0)

Comment: also returns object expected.

Comment: @todd: From where do you call `doRetrieveData`? If its for example a button. You could pass the ID to the function by adding the onclick event from codebehind. For example: `BtnRetrieveData.Attributes.Add("onclick,"doRetrieveData("+ hidOrg.ClientID +")");` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx

Comment: <select id="selDmaHierarchySelect" onchange="doRetrieveData(this.value)">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">Hierarchy</option>
        <option value="2">DMA</option>
        <option value="3">State</option>It is called from a dropdown list.  like this:

Comment: Then try my codebehind approach. Or put your hiddenfield next to the DropDownList and call `doRetrieveData(this.nextSibling.value)` to pass the hiddenfield-value directly from the DropDownList's clientside `onchange` event. http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_node_nextsibling.asp

Comment: Or set the hiddenfield's [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) to static if using .NET 4.0.

Comment: Your "Other Approach" number 1 did it for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
Response.Redirect("~/summary.aspx?multiple=" + hidOrg.Value);
```

Comment: That returns, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'hidOrg' is undefined"